# El texto dentro de un archivo, se desplaza a la derecha al compilar - Latex

Tags: latex

Estoy programando un documento en Latex, el cual uso con bastante regularidad y entiendo su funcionamiento en aspectos generales. Hace bastante trabajo con un repositorio pequeño con funciones y parámetros que ex compañeros de trabajo crearon hace años, por lo que hay bastantes cosas que suelo usar, sin cuestionarme mucho el cómo funcionan.
En este caso, la función `\inputArchivo[]{}` falla cuando se encuentra dentro de un bloque `'itemize'`.
Debo agregar que eso funciona bien en otros escenarios.

```
    \begin{itemize}
       \item Texto del enunciado
             %el ejemplo para este item va justo debajo
             \inputArchivo[nombreVisible.txt]{Textos/nombreReal.txt}
        \item otro texto
    \end{itemize}
```

Y al compilar, se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: Resultado al compilar el doc original]

La definición en el archivo de configuración es así:

[image: Definición de la función personalizada]

¿Cómo puedo corregir esa función para evitar este error?

Answer (score 1):

Basta con usar `resetmargins=true`, pues tanto `itemize` como `enumerate` agregan un margen a la izquierda (para respetar el espacio de cada `\item`), por lo que puedes usar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\inputArchivo}[2][]{%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\texttt{#1}}\\\hline
            \lstinputlisting[resetmargins=true]{#2}\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

    Afuera del itemize.
    \inputArchivo[foo.txt]{src/foo.txt}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item Dentro del itemize.
          \inputArchivo[foo.txt]{src/foo.txt}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

### Dando el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta información la encontré en la [documentación](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) de `listings` (Sección: *4.3.9 Margins and line shape*, página 35)